# Долго выполняется count()

Tags: mysql

Делаю отложенную загрузку таблицы с постраничным выводом и для того что бы рассчитывать количество страниц нужно делать выборку на количество записей. Если вводятся фильтры, то нужно каждый раз делать новую выборку на количество.

Есть запрос такого рода:

```
SELECT COUNT( T1.id ) FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.int1 = T2.int1
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref         rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      T1      index   int1            int1    8   NULL        425121  Using index
1   SIMPLE      T2      ref     int1            int1    8   base.T1.int 1       Using index
```

Выполняется ужасно долго(бывает по 2 минуты грузится), даже в самом мускуле запрос делается долго, индексы стоят, что же можно сделать что бы работало быстрее.

Comment: а если запрос переписать так

    SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.int1 = T2.int1

Comment: Такая ситуация бывает при крайне неселективном индексе. Т.е. если одно и то же значение int1 присутствует в очень большом (например, половине) записей в обеих таблицах.

Попробуйте **удалить индексы** по int1.

Comment: а вообще зачем вам количество страниц ?

Comment: SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.int1 = T2.int1

не помогло, но разве замена на * могла на что то повлиять ?

> Попробуйте удалить индексы по int1.

Если их удалить полностью то запрос вешает мускул, если удалить только с одной стороны, то count проходит быстрее, но вот селект теперь идет долго.

> а вообще зачем вам количество страниц
> ?

При отложенной загрузке нужно высчитывать количество страниц для пагинации, грузится не 500к записей, а 100 строк, но мы же должны видеть что их 500к и иметь возможность переключатся между ними.

Comment: считайте примерное количество, как все, кто с большими данными работает. если запрошена страница больше нужной, выдавайте последнюю, но вообще у вас действительно какой-то плохой поиск в T1/T2 я бы даже наверное посоветовал немного "лишней" информации писать, про связь вот этих T1/T2 таблиц, чтобы при попытке вывести предпоследнюю страницу не пришлось копать всю дату. И еще вопрос, у вас в T1 или T2 нет ячеек типа text/blob ?  если есть то гуглите *mysql barracuda*

Comment: Юзеру выдаются последние попавшие в таблицу строки(в минуту может добавится около 100 записей). Примерное количество строк можно взять из системных таблиц, а что делать если в работу включаются фильтры, тогда выводимых строк может стать от 0 до полного размера таблицы, как тогда считать примерное количество ? Ячеек типа text/blob нету.

Comment: тогда никакого смысла в пагинации нет, сделайте вместо страниц фильтр по дате (тем более что вы последние показываете).

Comment: спасибо за идею, попробую на днях

Answer (score 1):

1. Может быть, посмотрите в сторону INNER JOIN между T1 и T2 ?

Comment: а разве это не тоже самое? тем не менее никаких изменений не дало.

Comment: @sonniy это не то же самое - попробуйте:

    SELECT COUNT( T1.id ) FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.int1 = T2.int1

Comment: > тем не менее никаких изменений не дало

Comment: @Barmaley а где можно почитать про разницу?

Comment: OMG. group by не забываем народ.

Comment: @sonniy, [википедия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) утверждает, что разницы между INNER JOIN, LEFT INNER JOIN и Вашим случаем 

    FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.int1 = t2.int2

нет никакой.

--

Кстати, а что вообще хранится в T1 и T2, раз уж приходится делать столь неудачное соединение? 

Может оказаться, что лучше пойти на нарушение нормализации и часть данных продублировать в одной из таблиц.

Comment: аккаунты и инвентари связанные по id аккаунтов

Comment: А тогда "случайно" 

    SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.int1 = T2.int1

не равен ли

    SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM T2

или у Вас есть "бесхозные"  инвентари (с несуществующими id аккаунтов) ?